# How to create Declaration page in admin control panel

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, custom

Am using **magento 1.9** in `sales>order` am creating a custom `url` for **Declaration**, following image will explain you

[image]

Here am creating a link for `Silver Exchange Declaration`. This `url` like this

> http://127.0.0.1/ramesh/sliver-exchange/index.php/admin/sales_order/declaration/order_id/293/key/5589e8a0b2c3c3c5f1bd6decddfbfd05/

This my query how to create declaration page inside `admin>sales>order`